# Check for file in Firefox cache in Webdriver

Tags: javascript, firefox, caching, webdriver

I need to code a test, which check if browser cached correctly some piece of data (just check if cache created for some files or not).
Is there a way to do this in WebDriver or JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

The cache directory for Firefox lives under the `Cache` folder in the user's firefox profile folder. This can be queried using the normal `IO` classes in your language (i.e `System.IO` in C#)

However, the files here have no extensions or naming conventions, but I believe they are direct copies of the files. (They are complete copies of Javascript files, for instance)

You would probably have to compare all the files and use a hash comparison to check if something exists or not.

Comment: Yeah, thank I thought about that already, but I hoping there is more convenient way